# Вывод страницы с поддомена

Tags: php, парсер

Есть два сайта, на домене и поддомене, написанных на PHP.

Нужно с одного сайта выводить страницу статистики на втором сайте. Для примера, страница статистики имеет ссылку http://poddomen.site.ru/counter.php.

Как её вывести на втором сайте? Страница подготовлена, и её нужно выводить целиком, ничего не вырезая.

Я читал как парсить страницу, вырезая ссылки и изображения, но как вывести страницу целиком не нашел.

---

Просьба к тем, кто хочет действительно ответить на вопрос:
Напишите код целиком.

Если не знаете или хотите поумничать - не пишите ничего.
Флудерастия - не приветствуется.

---

Попробовал использовать Curl:

```
    $url = "http://poddomen.site.ru/counter.php";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Страница выводится, но есть так же и сообщение, которое мне не понятно:

> string(724) " Содержание выводимой страницы "

То есть лишние символы - это **string(724) " "**
По какой причине это может быть?

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю просто использовать тег `iframe` для отображения одной странице внутри другой.

Answer (score 1):

если iframe Вас по не понятным причинам не устраивает - просто используйте Ваш скрипт из вложенного сайта?!

Парсер есть смысл использовать если у Вас нет доступа ни к данным ни к функционалу.

на примере `simplehtmldom`
вы можете получить страницу так

> file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

Comment: Я не знаю чем Вы пытаетесь парсить страницу, это не указано в вопросе. На примере simplehtmldom я скинул Вам получение страници
вот дока http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm